# flutter android Set as default Open supported links is turned on but Supoorted web addresses turn off

Tags: android, flutter, applinks, flutter-androidmanifest

I set up Android app links by looking at the following

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links

this is my assetlinks.json

https://kimjuno97.github.io/.well-known/assetlinks.json

this is part of my AndroidManifest.xml

```
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="kimjuno97.github.io" />
            </intent-filter>
```

The adb shell test works fine

```
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "https://kimjuno97.github.io/terms"' \
    com.hwc2.chaam_beta
```

But I want to go to the app first, not the web, when I press url as below

[image]

In order to do that, the following settings need to be turned on

[image]

[image]

I'm guessing the code below turns on Supported Web addresse.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
```

I don't know how to turn on Supported Web addresse.

How do I turn this option on?

I don't know how to approach android because I don't know well.

**This issue is currently resolved.
When I distributed it to Google Play, there was no tunnel on or off in the first place.
You can have a similar experience with me, so I'll leave it in the comments.**

Below is after Google Play Publishing

[image: google play pub]